# getsockname() without bind()

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, unix-socket

I'm trying to get the port number of the socket, without calling bind().
The code is as follows.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0);
  struct sockaddr_in sin;
  socklen_t len = sizeof(sin);
  if (getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len) == -1) {
      perror("getsockname");
  } else {
      printf("port number %d\n", ntohs(sin.sin_port));
  }
}
```

it always print **"port number 0"**.

Is it mandatory to call bind() to use getsockname()? I saw similar statement mentioned from internet, but i cannot find a solid statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From man page:

> The getsockname() function shall retrieve the locally-**bound** name of the specified socket,
>
> (...)
>
> If the socket has not been **bound** to a local name, the value stored in the object pointed to by address is **unspecified**.

from [POSIX getsockname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getsockname.html), bold are mine.

So yes, you need to bind the socket.